# Async method to return true or false on React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I'm working on a React component that handles a form submit.

```
<form
    name="theForm"
    ref={(el) => { this.theForm = el }}
    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
    noValidate
>
```

On the submit event handler I perform validation, using HTML5 form checkvalidity() calling another function, validateForm();

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.validateForm()) {
        //Call the api to post data
    }
}
```

If the validity on validateForm is false, I populate a list on state called dirtyFormInputs that is passed to the form's child components.

Due to setState async behaviour, I changed my code to handle the updates to dirtyFormInputs list with async/await as follows:

```
async validateForm() {
    const formLength = this.theForm.length;

    if (this.theForm.checkValidity() === false) {
        this.setState({ dirtyFormInputs: [] });  
        for(let input of this.theForm){
            input.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'button' 
                && await this.validateInput(input);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But since I changed the validateInput method to properly update dirtyFormInputs, the return false statement on validateForm() is not effective anymore and my form is submitted even when failing on valitidy check.

```
validateInput(input) {
    if (!input.validity.valid) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.setState({
                dirtyFormInputs: [...this.state.dirtyFormInputs, input.name]
            }, resolve)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: an Asynch method can not, by it's asynchronous nature, return anything, except maybe a Promise in the new world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validateForm` returns a promise since it's declared `async`.

You need to wait for the promise to resolve:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.validateForm().then(result => { // or use `async` + `await`
    if (!result) return; 
    //Call the api to post data
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Async effect infects everything it touches. So you need to handle async nature of your validation inside `handleSubmit`

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (await this.validateForm()) {
        //Call the api to post data
    }
}
```